# unable to change image of aspx from c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to change the image in the page_load function of my page in which it retrieves the image from the databases and set that image to the image-view id. the retrieval is successful but the image is not changing when the page is loaded.

Comment: We can't tell you what's wrong with code you're not showing us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many times the images get cached and do not change on refresh/load. You can attach an additional parameter to the image source to get it being fetched afresh every time from the server.

***Assuming*** you are assigning image path to the image control named `ImagePreviewPhoto` you can do it as:

In C#:

```
ImagePreviewPhoto.ImageUrl = "your_image_path_and_name.ext?imag=" + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();
```

or in JavaScript:

```
ImagePreviewPhoto.src = 'your_image_path_and_name.ext?imag=' + Math.random();
```

Notice additional **imag** parameter with variable value

Comment: it is giving error on Now.Second.ToString().... "Now does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Now is used to access current time. You can try using FQN `DateTime.Now.ToString`